# Difference between BAPI_ACC_GL_POSTING_POST and BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, bapi

I need to know the difference between BAPI_ACC_GL_POSTING_POST and BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST that are very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BAPI_ACC_GL_POSTING_POST seems to be a simpler, functionally estricted BAPI for posting documents in general ledger. BAPI_ACC_DOCUMENT_POST is more general, can post documents in general ledger as well as in other areas like billing, goods movement etc.

BAPI_ACC_GL_POSTING_POST seems to exist to make posting documents in general ledger a bit easier.